# Set a cookie (django) and get its value

Tags: javascript, django, cookies

I need to set a cookie on multiple domains (cross-domaine cookie).
In order to do that, I've done a django server which creates the cookie.
I then need to "read" the cookie from other domains where I call this django cookies server.

If I call it through an img, the cookie is well set. But with the image, I can't access the cookie. 
I've tried with a javascript script, for example :

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

But each time I call this fonction, a new value is given for the cookie (it does not put the cookie on my browser). Is there a way to achieve what I want ? To get this cookie value with a javascript request ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try `set_cookie()` to set cookie

say if you have a json response `json_obj`

```
return_obj = HttpResponse(json_obj)
return_obj.set_cookie("custom_cookie_name", custom_cookie_value)
return return_obj
```

To verify if a request has custom cookie, try

```
if request.COOKIES.has_key("custom_cookie_name"):
   print "has custom cookie"
```

To get cookie value , try

```
custom_cookie = request.COOKIES.get('custom_cookie_name')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to set a cookie with django. But I need to get its value from another domain, with a javascript request. It seems that if I do the request though javascript, the django server can't identify the cookie (so can't identify the browser). Thanks! :)

Comment: I don't think you can get a cookie from another domain with javascript. That would violate the cross-domain limitations.

Comment: Yep, but it should be possible to read the cookie (by the django server) and return its value through a get request?